# styled-component does not inherit props passed through attrs method in react-native

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

Recently we updated our project targeting **RN072.5** with the latest version of styled-components **6.0.8**

```
"dependencies": {
  ...,
  "react": "18.2.0",
  "react-is": "18.2.0",
  "react-native": "0.72.5",
  "styled-components": "6.0.7",
  "stylis": "^4.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  ...,
  "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.1",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.54.1",
  "@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "^5.54.1",
  "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.1.4",
},
resolutions: {
  "styled-components": "^6"
}
```

given the following component, typescript recognise *source* and *resizeMode* as valid props

```
const BlurImage = styled.Image.attrs({
  source: blur,
  resizeMode: 'stretch'
})`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;
```

but when I try to use the components, it gives me the following error

[image]

```
Property  source  is missing in type  {}  but required in type
FastOmit<FastOmit<Substitute<ImageProps, ImageProps & RefAttributes<Image>>, never>, never>
```

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for a "better solution" I will post you my my quick and dirty workaround if you need to "make it work ASAP.

I just type as "optional" my default properties. I needed to downgrade `styled-components` to `6.0.7` version in order to make it work.

```
const BlurImage = styled(Image).attrs<{ source?: ImageSourcePropType | undefined }>({
  source: blur,
  resizeMode: 'stretch'
})`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
`;
```

In this way `<BlurImage />` can be used without the *(wrongly-typed)* mandatory `source`.
**This is not** a solution btw, because components with many properties become very long to write and type. And, if you will forget to specify it, an error will be thrown during execution, but not in TS.

You can also type it as `.attrs<Partial<ImageProps>>`, but this is even more dangerous, since hides **all** mandatory props.

Answer (score 0):

This is a not specific error that occurs when you forget to pass one of the mandatory props (even if it's mandatory only on one of the components in your inheritance chain). It doesn't tell which one, but throws this overload error.
Thats also the reason why `.attrs<Partial<ImageProps>>` helps - it makes every property optional.

Comment: Yes, but it used to work with styled-components 5. And the prop **is** actually specified inside the attrs of the styled-components, so it's expected not to be required in the `JSX` part, I suppose.